# What is the proper use of extern and static?

Tags: c, static, call, declaration, extern

In C, when stating `extern` or `static` specifiers on a function, what is the proper syntax use - 
only on declaration? on definition? both? is it the same with a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: terminology: it's declaration and definition.

Comment: @asaelr I meant declaration, fixed

Comment: @KarolyHorvath my mistake, confused. I meant declaration, definition and call.

Comment: How do you write `extern` on call?

Comment: @asaelr fixed another mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Declaring a `extern` Function:**

The keyword `extern` should be used only while declaring(not defining) a function.Note that functions by default have external linkage so the keyword `extern` on a function declaration is redundant.

```
extern void doSomething();
```

**Defining a `extern` Function:**

The function definition should not be specified with `extern` keyword. The definition could be in another cpp file.

```
void doSomething()
{
}
```

**Declaring a `static` Function:**
A `static` function restricts the use of the function to the Translation Unit in which it is declared. You need to specify the keyword when you declare it.

```
static void doSomething();
```

**Defining a `static` Function:**
The function definition needs to be defined in the same TU.You don't need to specify the `static` keyword while defining it.

```
void doSomething()
{
}
```

**Using a `extern` variable:**
You declare a variable as `extern` when you want to share the same global variable accross different translation Unit.
You need to declare the variable with `extern` keyword while you need to define it in one and only one cpp file.

**file1.h**

```
extern int i;
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include"file1.h"

int i = 10;
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "file1.h"

int main()
{
    i = 40;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'extern' can also be used when with variables. A good writeup of the whys/hows are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c

Comment: @gdc +1, and more important: on variables this keyword is not redundant, so this is the main use.

Answer (score 0):

stuff defined with *static* belongs to the current compilation unit (module).
Such stuff are NOT seen outside the unit

*extern* declares something which is somewhere else defined

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean in the words `on call`, but I assume you want to ask about `definition` and `declaration`.

The keyword `extern` means "This variable/function is defined somewhere else", so it's meaningless to use it on definition. You should use it only on declaration.

The keyword `static` (on functions and global variables) mean "don't export this symbol", You should write it on the first declaration (or definition) of the symbol.